# remove first occurring paragraph tag contents in string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, vb.net

How can i remove the first occurring paragraph tag contents in string.

```
Actual String
<p>Hello</p> <p>World</p>

Result
<p>World</p>
```

One option is to find the position of first `<p>` and first `</p>` and then replace everything with "" to position `</p>`

How can this be Achieved with regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the warnings about using regex to parse html...

**A. If First Paragraph Always Starts at the Beginning of the String**

- Search: `^<p>.*?</p>`
- Replace: empty string
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string.
- The lazy `.*?` ensures that we only match up to the first closing `</p>`

In C#:

```
string resultString = Regex.Replace(yourstring, "^<p>.*?</p>", "");
```

**B. If First Paragraph Can Start Anywhere**

- Search: `(?s)(\A.*?)<p>.*?</p>`
- Replace: in the delegate function, return Group 1.
- `(?s)` allows the dot to match newlines in case your first paragraph occurs after the first line
- In the `(\A.*?)` the `\A` asserts that we are at the beginning of the string, then the lazy `.*?` matches everything up to the first paragraph. This is all captured to Group 1.
- `<p>.*?</p>` matches the paragraph
- The replacement is Group 1, so the paragraph is deleted.

Here is a full C# program to show how this works (see output at the bottom of the [online demo](https://ideone.com/gPIcRU)).

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
class Program
{
static void Main() {
var myRegex = new Regex(@"(?s)(\A.*?)<p>.*?</p>");
string s1 = @"Hey! <p>Hello</p> <p>World</p>";

string replaced = myRegex.Replace(s1, delegate(Match m) {
return m.Groups[1].Value;
});
Console.WriteLine(replaced);

} // END Main
} // END Program
```

Comment: FYI Added full explanation for both methods. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Regex.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haekbhys.aspx) method defining the count (times the replacement can occur) to `1`

```
Regex rgx     = new Regex(@"<p>.*?</p>*");
String input  = @"<p>Hello</p> <p>World</p>";
String result = rgx.Replace(input, "", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could capture group in the string like this:

```
string input = @"<p>Hello</p> <p>World</p>";
string pattern = @"<p>(\w*)</p>";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
// matches[0] contains <p>Hello</p>
// matches[1] contains <p>World</p>
```